# How to use both Android and IOS simulator simultaneously to test my flutter app during development?

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, ios-simulator

I was wondering if I can set up and use both Android and iOS simulators simultaneously when I develop my flutter app? It makes things easier and allows me to catch platform-specific bugs earlier.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. If you have both iOs and Android emulators running, you can use the command `flutter run -d all` to launch on both devices. If you want to launch on one device with both open, you will have to specify which one by telling it the device id, like `flutter run -d emulator-5554`.

While developing I like to have the iOs emulator open for debugging in case I want to jump in and see the value of a particular variable at a particular moment, and the android emulator for running the app / designing / iterating.